# User database ownership in webapps

Tags: database, database-design

I am developing a webapp where each user will access his own data.

Think about pivotal tracker and the such as an example, and assume each user will store 2 different data types like so:

```
table project
id  |  name
0   |  foo
1   |  bar

table story
id  |  name  | effort
1   |  baz   | 5
2   |  ex    | 2
```

I can think of 2 solutions.

1) Provide each table with an additional `user_id` column so that each data is bound to his owner

2) Setup a new database schema for each new user

Personally, i am more on 2) because it would grant a higher security rate (not bound to the application level).

What would be the recommended way, and why?

Comment: It depends on your intended use of the data.  If you have many queries that aggregate data across diferent users, you'll regret creating separate schemas.  If you never do this, separate schemas will probably be easier overall.  You'll have more work todo babysitting many databases, but not a lot.

Comment: Thanks. Did you have any experience using separate schemas? Any objective data about the maintenance overhead this solution will cause?

Comment: I never built parallel scemas, but I have been called in to fix up databases built that way.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2 appears rather exotic to me. It means creating new database schemas each time a user is added. Now, if you have very few users, and new users only get added very rarely, this may be feasible. But if you have lots of users to accomodate, you will need an automatism to create those schemas on the fly. Sure this is possible, but you will leave the grounds of existing tools and frameworks that support your development. E.g., Java Persistency API links a Java class to a table and won't support dynamic data base definition.

Also, I have doubts concerning the security level. In a web app, the database "user" is not the actual human user behind the browser, but the application server, which owns a database connection for its entire runtime. Therefore, individual human user's access rights aren't handled by the database, but by the application.